# Proving a expectation of cdf relationship

Tags: probability

Suppose Z follows standard normal and $\Phi(.)$ denotes corresponding cdf. K is any positive constant. How to prove$E[Z\Phi(KZ)]=KE[Z\Phi(Z/K)] $?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts? $$E[Z\Phi(KZ)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(Kz)z\phi(z)\,\mathrm dz=-\Phi(Kz)\phi(z)\Bigr|_{-\infty}^\infty +\int_{-\infty}^\infty K\phi(Kz)\phi(z)\,\mathrm dz$$ where the first term on the right disappears upon substitution of the limits?

Comment: I don't think this way works. And your integration by parts contain some errors in it.

Comment: mathlearner: I suggest that you withdraw your comment since both its parts are unfounded, as the accepted answer shows (and maybe that you ponder the reasons which made you react inappropriately to @Dilip's hint).

Comment: @Did Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ denote the density of a standard normal random variable, thus $\varphi(z)=\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$, $\varphi'(z)=-z\varphi(z)$ and $\Phi(z)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^z\varphi(u)\mathrm du$. For every positive $K$, an integration by parts yields 
$$E[Z\Phi(KZ)]=\int z\varphi(z)\Phi(Kz)\mathrm dz=-\int\varphi'(z)\Phi(Kz)\mathrm dz=\int K\varphi(z)\varphi(Kz)\mathrm dz.
$$
By the change of variable $u=Kz$,
$$
\int K\varphi(z)\varphi(Kz)\mathrm dz=K\cdot\int K^{-1}\varphi(u)\varphi(K^{-1}u)\mathrm du.
$$
Identifying the integral in the RHS, one gets
$$
E[Z\Phi(KZ)]=K\cdot E[Z\Phi(K^{-1}Z)].
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you explain why the second equality holds? And how we get the RHS?

Comment: Second equality: $z\varphi(z)=-\varphi'(z)$. // RHS: integration by parts (as written in the post) and $K\varphi(Kz)$ the derivative of $\Phi(Kz)$ with respect to $z$.